# Can a Tunisian with a US A-2 visa visit Canada?

Tags: visas, canada, tunisian-citizens

I am Tunisian and I am in the USA and on an A-2 visa. Can I visit Canada?

Answer (score 3):

Citizens and permanent residents of the US can visit Canada without a visa, but other US visa types do not give you the right to enter Canada.

You will need to apply for a Canadian visa.

Source: http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp and http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1020&top=16

Answer (score 1):

Canadian visa requirements are independent of US visa requirements, with some exceptions that do not apply to you. (US permanent residents don't need a visa to visit Canada, but as you are in A-2 status, you are clearly not a permanent resident.)

So, you can visit Canada if you apply for a Canadian visa and the application is successful.

I presume your US visa is valid for multiple entries, but if it is not, you may want to renew it before you go to Canada.